# Android: problem scrolling my activity including a WebView

Tags: android, webview

I included a WebView in my activity and load some Javascript in it which is then going to get data from an external website.
This works and displays fine but the problem is that my activity doesn't scroll when the WebView is done loading so I can't see the bottom of the WebView such as all the other Views I put below this. Any idea of how I should handle this?
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using scrollview in your layout? Try that and see if that helps.

Here is a link to the developer [page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Comment: You cannot use a `ScrollView` with a `WebView`, AFAIK. `ScrollView` does not work well with other widgets that know intrinsically how to scroll.

Comment: You are correct, i forgot you were using webview. Then it sounds like you may have a layout issue, where you may be filling things incorrectly. Like the suggestion made by commonsware.

Comment: I actually just got through reading an article about scrollview working with webview with a few tricks, was about to make a comment about that, glad to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

> This works and displays fine but the problem is that my activity doesn't scroll when the WebView is done loading so I can't see the bottom of the WebView such as all the other Views I put below this.

You need to change your layout such that the "other Views I put below this" will be on the screen, and the `WebView` simply takes up the remaining space.

For example, here is a layout showing a `WebView` with a `Button`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webkit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <Button android:id="@+id/helpcast"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View Helpcast"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Because the `WebView` is set up with a `0px` height but a weight of `1`, and because the `Button` specifies no weight, the `WebView` will fill all space left over after the `Button` is on-screen. The `WebView` content will scroll inside the `WebView` itself, if needed, based upon whatever Web page you load in there.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I managed to do what I wanted using a ScrollView. However I couldn't get any scroll using the android:layout_height="0px"
android:layout_weight="1"